# Import Logic app built in Azure Portal into Visual Studio with parameters

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I want to import Logic Apps made in Azure portal imported in Visual Studio Project for Logic Apps.

I can download Logic App via Cloud Explorer & import from using this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/manage-logic-apps-with-visual-studio.

But after adding that visual studio to run or deploy I need to create parameter file manually. Is there some way to download existing Logic Apps with parameters so that when imported in Visual Studio that can be ready for run when committed in source control after downloading & adding to Visual Studio.

I have seen request for this feature in Azure supported by 211 votes but yet to be picked.
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/31833445-allow-to-export-logic-app-with-parameters-to-be-se

I am looking if anyone found some way to do this...

Comment: Any process now?

Answer (score 1):

As the [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/31833445-allow-to-export-logic-app-with-parameters-to-be-se) you provided, it seems that the feature of exporting logic app with parameter directly does not exist now. You could **vote up it to promote the implementation of the function**.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://blog.mexia.com.au/preparing-azure-logic-apps-for-cicd).

Comment: Voted already with 3 votes, but was looking if someone already has done that

Comment: If the function already exists, no one will vote up this any more. So, maybe you could communicate with developer teams to check and promote it.

Comment: I am not able to find anything like this except new feature request for LogicApps by users to Azure Team. Yes, we are doing deployment & development from VS but some work is already done & needs import.May be we  write parameters templates manually now.